# Logs in Ubuntu 20.04 to investigate theft

Tags: ubuntu, logs

At my work, I have a small server PC running Ubuntu 20.04. A week ago, someone stole the CPU (yes, they took the case apart, removed the fan, removed the CPU and then put the fan and everything else back as it was) leaving everything else untouched.

As I have an original hard drive, is there a way to plug it into another PC as an external drive and find any log file which would tell me at what time the server was switched off?

I was not able to replace the CPU as I could not find a replacement which would fit the socket.

Alternatively, if I plugged the drive into another PC, would it boot my OS?

Comment: There is no need to have it boot. You can connect the drive, boot a live USB of Ubuntu or Fedora or anything else, and then mount the root partition and then examine the logs.

Comment: Ok, but which logs, where are they? Which one would show power cut?

Comment: Maybe checking with the local network devices, like DHCP server or anything else your server connects to regularly, might show when it missed it's scheduled connection? Or as Nasir comments, do not boot the drive, just mount it ro and view the logs, or just look for the time of the newest modified file

Comment: If the computer shut down uncleanly, mounting the filesystem, even read-only, might recover the journal and adjust metadata.

Comment: @MattNordhoff then they'll just have to clone it before mounting it 

Comment: > *I could not find yet the replacement which would fit the socket.*  That's the problem the thief had, obviously. He or she made it your problem.

Comment: For journaled ext filesystems there's also the mount option `noload` combined with `ro`: *"For example, ext3 and ext4 will replay the journal if the filesystem is dirty. To prevent this kind of write access, you may want to mount an ext3 or ext4 filesystem with the **`ro,noload`** mount options or set the block device itself to read-only mode, see the **blockdev** (8) command."* @MattNordhoff  That's a good one to remember for any data recovery. The `blockdev` commands appear to be `--getro` to check, and `--setro` / `--setrw`, run before mounting

Comment: *I was not able to re-place the CPU as I could not find yet the replacement which would fit the socket.*  E-Bay has a lot of people selling used CPUs for practically any socket type (including ones that are e.g. server or laptop sockets).  You should be able to find one there.

Answer (score 29):

As Nasir Riley said in the comments, you don't need to boot from the server's disk. In fact, in order to protect the evidence, *you shouldn't boot it*.

If you plan to use the information as evidence in a court of law, you should only access the disk of the system in a read-only manner, and perhaps in the presence of qualified witness (= one that understands what you are planning to do and how it should be done) only. You might want to contact your local law enforcement for more specific advice on how to collect this kind of evidence.

If possible, make an exact image copy of the disk before doing anything else, and examine the copy while keeping the original secure.

You should start looking at `/var/log`: that's where essentially all system logs are located. If the thief let the system run a controlled shutdown, you might find log records of the shutdown.

But it is more likely that the thief just yanked out the power cord, and so you'll have to look at the logs to find the most recent log entry, and then try and figure out what would have been the next event that would have created a log entry (but didn't, because the system was no longer receiving power). That will give you a time window during which the server went down.

The frequency of log events depends on the configuration of the system: without knowing anything about applications the server was running and the normal pattern of its use, it's very difficult to say anything more definite.
A very verbose application log might give you the best estimate.

If the system uses actual server hardware (e.g. multiple hot-swappable power supplies, perhaps a dedicated remote management network port), it might have recorded the exact time of the power loss in its internal hardware error log stored in the non-volatile memory of the server's management processor. Through a remote management facility (like Dell iDRAC, Fujitsu RILOE, HP(E) iLO, Oracle ILOM etc.) you might be able to access the hardware error log even with the main processor missing, as long as the motherboard is receiving power.

But if such remote management facility is not already configured, it might not be possible to configure it while the main processor is missing. In that case, you will have to get what you can from the logs, and then maybe get the more detailed information later when you've managed to install a replacement CPU. `sudo ipmitool sel elist` should be the command to list the hardware error log, if one exists. Of course, vendor-specific tools might provide more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you, this is great advise. I will try most of it (I am not gonna involve court in this)